# Windbg get value from dictionary using TryGetValue

Tags: c#, dictionary, windbg

I have a dump from a IIS process that was consuming nearly 100% of CPU. I run windbg and after running the `!runaway` command, I found that the top threads were all stuck in a Dictionary `FindEntry(System.__Canon)` command. The stack of one of these threads start with:

```
0:043> !clrstack -p
OS Thread Id: 0x1740 (43)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
0000008646eecc78 00007ff810530c8a [RedirectedThreadFrame: 0000008646eecc78] 
0000008646eecd10 00007ffffe420ccd System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].FindEntry(System.__Canon)
    PARAMETERS:
        this = <no data>
        key = <no data>

0000008646eecd80 00007ffffe422ed4 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].TryGetValue(System.__Canon, System.__Canon ByRef)
    PARAMETERS:
        this = <no data>
        key = <no data>
        value = <no data>
```

I suspect my problem is something like [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2009/12/21/high-cpu-in-net-app-using-a-static-generic-dictionary.aspx), but I need some more evidence before concluding that. For that, I wish I could get the values or any other information regarding the dictionary. Looking at this code, there are 2 things different from majority of tutorials on the web:

1. The parameters shows as `System.__Canon`. What does it mean?
2. How do I get the value from a `TryGetValue`, as it only has a reference (ByRef) to the output, and the pointer is not listed on the "parameters" section.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check [.NET Type Internals - From a Microsoft CLR Perspective](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20481/NET-Type-Internals-From-a-Microsoft-CLR-Perspecti)

Comment: are you looking for examples of how to use TryGetValue

Comment: PerfView from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/10/09/improving-your-app-s-performance-with-perfview.aspx might be better suited for this than windbg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't shared the source code and you haven't written whether you are using static dictionaries so I'm assuming you are not. But you suspect that your dictionaries are shared among threads - let's find this out. `CLRStack` often fails to find parameters when you are in the middle of a method or when the code is highly optimized. The other very useful SOS command is `!DumpStackObjects` or `!dso`. It simply dumps all managed objects which are on the stack. You probably will be able to find there your key value (unless it's a basic type - then things will get a bit more complicated and I will need more info to help you). Example output might look as follows:

```
OS Thread Id: 0x1520 (0)
ESP/REG  Object   Name
ecx      020e21b4 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]]
edx      020e218c System.String    k1
esi      020e21b4 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]]
005BED6C 020e1228 System.String    
005BED70 020e218c System.String    k1
005BED78 020e45a4 System.IO.TextReader+SyncTextReader
005BED80 020e21b4 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]]
005BED90 020e217c System.Object[]    (System.String[])
005BEDA0 020e1228 System.String    
005BEDA4 020e21b4 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]]
005BEDA8 020e21b4 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]]
005BEDAC 020e21b4 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]]
005BEDB8 020e21a0 System.String    v1
005BEDBC 020e217c System.Object[]    (System.String[])
005BEE40 020e217c System.Object[]    (System.String[])
005BEFA4 020e217c System.Object[]    (System.String[])
005BEFD4 020e217c System.Object[]    (System.String[])
```

Notice that the dictionary is on the list. Run this command for each thread and verify that they share the dictionary addresses. `System.__Canon` is nothing you should be worried about - it's just a placeholder in generic types (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,a210e11a9e5f2deb). In the output above I had a `Dictionary<String,String>` instance and was looking for **k1** - as you can see it was also on the stack.

Comment: You can use `~*e!dso` to run the command on all threads. It will probably fail on native-only stacks.

Comment: @lowleveldesign Thanks for your reply. I didn't share the specifics cause I don't have the source code (all I have is the full dump of IIS). I look at the top 3 threads, and all of them shared the same dictionary address indeed. What would be the best way to make the connection and declare that the Dictionary search is the culprit of the hang process? I can see the total time of each thread with "!runaway", but is there a way to find how much time each thread is actually stuck in the same line?

Comment: @tyron unfortunately you won't be able to figure out when a given method started (this is what you usually use live debugging or logs for). The dictionary search is a culprit if multiple threads have the FindEntry method on their callstack (which is your case). Usually when you observe a CPU throttling you take few dumps with some delay (few seconds) between each dump. And then you compare the dumps to be sure that a given method is the problem. If you have only one dump you are left with some guessing.

Comment: I see your point, having multiple dumps would be handful for sure. I'll do that next time. Btw, you mention you have `Dictionary<String,String>`, and then you can look after "k1". My case, I guess there is `Dictionary<Canon,Canon>` , right? Any chance I can find what was the variable value by that time? Both `this` and `key` shows "<no data>" on my example, so there is nothing I could `!dso` on :(

Comment: No, !dso will show you all managed objects available on the stack - with high probability keys are there. Canon is just a placeholder type. If you can't find them, then you need to analyze assembly code which was executed before the current instruction pointer (the place where your thread is stopped) and find out where is the value passed to the method (at the beginning it was probably in the RDX registry).

Comment: Ok, understood. And is there a way to map back to the code (i.e. know what part of the code triggered the Dictionary.FindEntry command)? Using something like a Reflector or ILSpy...?

Comment: With `!CLRStack` you see the whole stack - you have there also offsets to the beginning of the method. These are assembly offsets, but by examining assembly you should be able to find the approximate place in the C# code. Check also `!U` command which nicely resolves .NET method calls in the assembly.